# Why outer join does not preserve all mentioned columns after data frame join in scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frames on which i perform outer join .
Data frame 1 data set is like this

```
Source.organizationId|^|Source.sourceId|^|FilingDateTime|^|SourceTypeCode|^|DocumentId|^|Dcn|^|DocFormat|^|StatementDate|^|IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|^|ContainsPreliminaryData|^|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|^|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|^|ContainsRestatement|^|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|^|ThirdPartySourceCode|^|ThirdPartySourcePriority|^|SourceTypeId|^|ThirdPartySourceCodeId|^|FFAction|!|
4295876791|^|162|^|2017-08-10T06:01:00Z|^|YUH|^|44604379|^|yo00196838|^|PDFNTV|^|2017-06-30T00:00:00Z|^|False|^|False|^|2017-06-30T00:00:00Z|^|1.00000|^|False|^|540|^|SS |^|1|^|3013057|^|1000716240|^|I|!|
4295877415|^|167|^|2005-03-31T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2005-03-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|168|^|2010-03-31T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2010-03-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|169|^|2007-03-31T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2007-03-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|170|^|2014-12-31T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2014-12-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|171|^|2012-12-31T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2012-12-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|172|^|2009-03-31T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2009-03-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|194|^|2015-03-30T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2013-01-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|195|^|2008-05-06T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2008-01-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|214|^|2012-03-08T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2011-01-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|215|^|2004-06-30T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2004-01-01T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|216|^|2012-06-25T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2011-01-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|217|^|2014-01-14T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2014-01-05T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|218|^|2008-05-09T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2007-01-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|219|^|2010-12-09T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2011-01-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|220|^|2011-06-29T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2011-01-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|221|^|2013-06-29T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2014-01-05T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|222|^|2015-02-23T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2014-01-05T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|223|^|2013-05-31T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2014-01-05T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|224|^|2012-03-20T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2011-01-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^||^|False|^|0|^|ESG|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
4295877415|^|229|^|2015-12-31T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2015-12-31T00:00:00Z|^|True|^|False|^||^|1.00000|^|False|^|0|^|ATD|^||^|1002198005|^||^|I|!|
```

Data frame 2 is like below

```
DataPartition_1|^|TimeStamp|^|Source.organizationId|^|Source.sourceId|^|FilingDateTime_1|^|SourceTypeCode_1|^|DocumentId_1|^|Dcn_1|^|DocFormat_1|^|StatementDate_1|^|IsFilingDateTimeEstimated_1|^|ContainsPreliminaryData_1|^|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1|^|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1|^|ContainsRestatement_1|^|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset_1|^|ThirdPartySourceCode_1|^|ThirdPartySourcePriority_1|^|SourceTypeId_1|^|ThirdPartySourceCodeId_1|^|FFAction_1
SelfSourcedPublic|^|1512723204932|^|4295859031|^|59|^|2017-04-04T18:00:00+00:00|^|10Q|^|null|^|null|^|null|^|2017-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|^|false|^|false|^|2017-03-31T00:00:00+00:00|^|1.00000|^|false|^|-360|^|SS|^|1|^|3011836|^|1000716240|^|I|!|
```

And here is the schema of both data frame

First schema root

```
 |-- Source_organizationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Source_sourceId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FilingDateTime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SourceTypeCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DocumentId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Dcn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DocFormat: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StatementDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsFilingDateTimeEstimated: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- ContainsPreliminaryData: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CumulativeAdjustmentFactor: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ContainsRestatement: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- FilingDateTimeUTCOffset: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ThirdPartySourceCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ThirdPartySourcePriority: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SourceTypeId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ThirdPartySourceCodeId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DataPartition: string (nullable = true)
Second schema root
 |-- DataPartition_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Source_organizationId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Source_sourceId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FilingDateTime_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SourceTypeCode_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DocumentId_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Dcn_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DocFormat_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StatementDate_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsFilingDateTimeEstimated_1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- ContainsPreliminaryData_1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ContainsRestatement_1: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- FilingDateTimeUTCOffset_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ThirdPartySourceCode_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ThirdPartySourcePriority_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- SourceTypeId_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ThirdPartySourceCodeId_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- FFAction_1: string (nullable = true)
```

Now when i perform outer join then in the output field few columns are missing

Here is the sample output

```
Source.organizationId|^|Source.sourceId|^|FilingDateTime|^|SourceTypeCode|^|DocumentId|^|Dcn|^|DocFormat|^|StatementDate|^|IsFilingDateTimeEstimated|^|ContainsPreliminaryData|^|CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate|^|CumulativeAdjustmentFactor|^|ContainsRestatement|^|FilingDateTimeUTCOffset|^|ThirdPartySourceCode|^|ThirdPartySourcePriority|^|SourceTypeId|^|ThirdPartySourceCodeId|^|FFAction|!|
4295877415|^|217|^|2014-01-14T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2014-01-05T00:00:00Z|^|true|^|false|^||^||^|false|^|0|^|ESG|^|1002198005|^|I|!|
4295877415|^|171|^|2012-12-31T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2012-12-31T00:00:00Z|^|true|^|false|^||^||^|false|^|0|^|ESG|^|1002198005|^|I|!|
4295877415|^|167|^|2005-03-31T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2005-03-31T00:00:00Z|^|true|^|false|^||^||^|false|^|0|^|ESG|^|1002198005|^|I|!|
4295877415|^|219|^|2010-12-09T00:00:00Z|^|ESGWEB|^||^||^||^|2011-01-31T00:00:00Z|^|true|^|false|^||^||^|false|^|0|^|ESG|^|1002198005|^|I|!|
```

So here `ThirdPartySourceCodeId` and `ThirdPartySourcePriority` is missing where it is blank in the first data frame .For example in the second row of the first data.

There are 19 columns in the first data frame but in the output i get only 17 columns.

Here is the full code to generate output

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
    import java.sql.{Date, Timestamp}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val get_cus_val = spark.udf.register("get_cus_val", (filePath: String) => filePath.split("\\.")(3))

val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialSource/MAIN")

val df1With_ = df.toDF(df.columns.map(_.replace(".", "_")): _*)
val column_to_keep = df1With_.columns.filter(v => (!v.contains("^") && !v.contains("!") && !v.contains("_c"))).toSeq
val df1result = df1With_.select(column_to_keep.head, column_to_keep.tail: _*)
val df1resultFinal=df1result.withColumn("DataPartition", get_cus_val(input_file_name))

val df1resultFinalwithTimestamp=df1resultFinal
.withColumn("FilingDateTime",date_format(col("FilingDateTime"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
.withColumn("StatementDate",date_format(col("StatementDate"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
.withColumn("CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate",date_format(col("CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
.withColumn("CumulativeAdjustmentFactor", format_number(col("CumulativeAdjustmentFactor"), 5))

val df2 = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialSource/INCR")
val df2With_ = df2.toDF(df2.columns.map(_.replace(".", "_")): _*)
val df2column_to_keep = df2With_.columns.filter(v => (!v.contains("^") && !v.contains("!") && !v.contains("_c"))).toSeq
val df2result = df2With_.select(df2column_to_keep.head, df2column_to_keep.tail: _*)

val df2resultTimestamp=df2result
.withColumn("FilingDateTime_1",date_format(col("FilingDateTime_1"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
.withColumn("StatementDate_1",date_format(col("StatementDate_1"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
.withColumn("CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1",date_format(col("CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"))
.withColumn("CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1", format_number(col("CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1"), 5))


import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Source_organizationId", "Source_sourceId").orderBy($"TimeStamp".cast(LongType).desc) 
val latestForEachKey = df2resultTimestamp.withColumn("rank", rank().over(windowSpec)).filter($"rank" === 1).drop("rank", "TimeStamp")


val dfMainOutput = df1resultFinalwithTimestamp.join(latestForEachKey, Seq("Source_organizationId", "Source_sourceId"), "outer")
      .select($"Source_organizationId", $"Source_sourceId",
        when($"FilingDateTime_1".isNotNull, $"FilingDateTime_1").otherwise($"FilingDateTime").as("FilingDateTime"),
        when($"SourceTypeCode_1".isNotNull, $"SourceTypeCode_1").otherwise($"SourceTypeCode").as("SourceTypeCode"),
        when($"DocumentId_1".isNotNull, $"DocumentId_1").otherwise($"DocumentId").as("DocumentId"),
        when($"Dcn_1".isNotNull, $"Dcn_1").otherwise($"Dcn").as("Dcn"),
        when($"DocFormat_1".isNotNull, $"DocFormat_1").otherwise($"DocFormat").as("DocFormat"),
        when($"StatementDate_1".isNotNull, $"StatementDate_1").otherwise($"StatementDate").as("StatementDate"),
        when($"IsFilingDateTimeEstimated_1".isNotNull, $"IsFilingDateTimeEstimated_1").otherwise($"IsFilingDateTimeEstimated").as("IsFilingDateTimeEstimated"),
        when($"ContainsPreliminaryData_1".isNotNull, $"ContainsPreliminaryData_1").otherwise($"ContainsPreliminaryData").as("ContainsPreliminaryData"),
        when($"CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1".isNotNull, $"CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate_1").otherwise($"CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate").as("CapitalChangeAdjustmentDate"),
        when($"CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1".isNotNull, $"CumulativeAdjustmentFactor_1").otherwise($"CumulativeAdjustmentFactor").as("CumulativeAdjustmentFactor"),
        when($"ContainsRestatement_1".isNotNull, $"ContainsRestatement_1").otherwise($"ContainsRestatement").as("ContainsRestatement"),
        when($"FilingDateTimeUTCOffset_1".isNotNull, $"FilingDateTimeUTCOffset_1").otherwise($"FilingDateTimeUTCOffset").as("FilingDateTimeUTCOffset"),
        when($"ThirdPartySourceCode_1".isNotNull, $"ThirdPartySourceCode_1").otherwise($"ThirdPartySourceCode").as("ThirdPartySourceCode"),
        when($"ThirdPartySourcePriority_1".isNotNull, $"ThirdPartySourcePriority_1").otherwise($"ThirdPartySourcePriority").as("ThirdPartySourcePriority"),
        when($"SourceTypeId_1".isNotNull, $"SourceTypeId_1").otherwise($"SourceTypeId").as("SourceTypeId"),
        when($"ThirdPartySourceCodeId_1".isNotNull, $"ThirdPartySourceCodeId_1").otherwise($"ThirdPartySourceCodeId").as("ThirdPartySourceCodeId"),
        when($"FFAction_1".isNotNull, concat(col("FFAction_1"), lit("|!|"))).otherwise(concat(col("FFAction"), lit("|!|"))).as("FFAction"),
        when($"DataPartition_1".isNotNull, $"DataPartition_1").otherwise($"DataPartition").as("DataPartition"))
        .filter(!$"FFAction".contains("D"))

val dfMainOutputFinal = dfMainOutput.na.fill("").select($"DataPartition",concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))

val headerColumn = df.columns.filter(v => (!v.contains("^") && !v.contains("_c"))).toSeq

val header = headerColumn.dropRight(1).mkString("", "|^|", "|!|")

val dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull = dfMainOutputFinal.withColumn("concatenated", regexp_replace(col("concatenated"), "null", "")).withColumnRenamed("concatenated", header)


dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.repartition(1).write.partitionBy("DataPartition")
  .format("csv")
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .option("delimiter", ";")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("codec", "gzip")
  .save("s3://trfsmallfffile/FinancialSource/output")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your both columns, `ThirdPartySourceCodeId` and `ThirdPartySourcePriority`, after join are of `integerType`, so `na.fill("")` didn't work for them and thus when you used `concat`, all `null` `integer` values got `filtered` out.

the solution to your problem is to cast the two columns into `stringType` before applying `na.fill`

so changing

```
val dfMainOutputFinal = dfMainOutput.na.fill("").select($"DataPartition",concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))
```

to

```
val dfMainOutputFinal = dfMainOutput.withColumn("ThirdPartySourcePriority", $"ThirdPartySourcePriority".cast(StringType)).withColumn("ThirdPartySourceCodeId", $"ThirdPartySourceCodeId".cast(StringType)).na.fill("").select($"DataPartition",concat_ws("|^|", dfMainOutput.schema.fieldNames.filter(_ != "DataPartition").map(c => col(c)): _*).as("concatenated"))
```

should solve your issue